# how to convert int to hexadecimal color format in java

Tags: java, colors, hex

I have real numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,...

I want to convert int to hexadecimal format.

```
Integer.toHexString(-number-);
```

This works, but it's not in color format.

For example:

```
int a = 32;
```

must be converted to    000020. These zeros come automatically.

any help ?

Comment: And how does it know that 32 is the B value in RGB?

Comment: You have to concatenate the 3 primary colors Red, Green and Blue, to have the color code: [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)

Answer (score 1):

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & number));
```

does this.